# Pie chart exported PDF highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have several charts of type bar, pie and column chart. I am using one export module for all type of the charts. For example,

```
chart.exportChart({

       //here i use the title, font, width, marginTop, marginLeft and filename etc.. 
})
```

I am facing a problem when i download a pie chart as other charts. I get my pie chart tooltips are chopped(Right and left tooltips in pie chart) in exported PDF. Is there any way, that i can shrink only the pie chart in exported PDF without changing the positions of Title and Subtitle and without effecting the other chart PDF exports.

Here is the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nkj2msvp/1/
For this how can i minimize the size of pie chart when it exported to PDF?

Comment: In case when I export [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nkj2msvp/2/) exampel without any chartOptions, I don't see cut / shrink labels.

Comment: Yes, anyhow, can i set the pie size only while exporting without using marginRight, spacingRight? Basically, i want to export smaller pie with size only while exporting?

Comment: You can set size paramter in chartOptions.

Comment: I am already using size in export options in the given fiddle but still not working.

Comment: Indeed it looks like somethign wrong with that, I added this note to our bugtracker [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1562)